# textarea with overflow:hidden is not showing the new added lines in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using a textarea styled with `overflow:hidden` to remove the scroll , the users can insert lines of text in this text area.

the problem is with firefox, when the text exceeds the height of the textarea the new lines will not appear on the textarea , I have to click on the down arrow key to see them,
while it works very fine on other browsers.

what I mean , writing multipe lines on a textarea with style `overflow:hidden` on firefox will show only the first lines till it reaches the end of the text area, the rest is hidden you need to move the curson to reach them.

I want the cursor to be on the line that I am writing and to display this line on the view of textarea

I **dont want to use javascript** at all

here is a sample code :

**HTML:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    resize: none;
}
```

and here is the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb7b4/)

is there any possible solution with HTML and CSS **only** ?

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want scroll and the issues appears only on firefox then you could do,

1. Add character limit to the textarea. Link: http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/
2. Use a textarea auto-grow plugin to expand the textarea height automatically, Check here http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 0):

Hi why don't you use jQuery? it does not bother like traditional js :)

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(9999)
})
```